# figuring out this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how the get the featured area

at http://blueoceanportfolios.com to link to webpages rather than displaying it within the featured box on the left .

This area is using JS file to display the videos on content in the featured box when different items on the menu are clicked, here is the working example :

http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/company/

Okay ,
**The problem:** Loading a new webpage rather than displaying the content at featured box at the homepage of above website

Tried solutions: linking to javascript functions like onclick="window.location="http://someplace.com";" etc but still the content loads up in the featured box , 
try clicking on 2) it displays stackoverflow.com rather than loading new page.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     onclick="window.location="http://someplace.com";"
         </script>
```

... is not the way to add event handlers to an element.  If you want those anchors to link to a web page, put the URL in the `href` attribute like any normal link:

```
<a href="http://someplace.com">Link text</a>
```